# urllib.request error!! no host given

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am quite new to Python and am currently learning it.  I have this small code:

```
import urllib.request

x = urllib.request.urlopen('https:\\www.google.com')

print(x.read())
```

When I run it Python shouts out this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/The Kids/Desktop/urllib.py", line 3, in <module>
x = urllib.request.urlopen('https:\\www.google.com')
File "C:\Program Files\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 162, in                    
urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 463, in open
req = meth(req)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1163, in             
do_request_
raise URLError('no host given')
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>
```

Could I please get help with this?

Comment: Your url is incorrect : replace \ with /.

Comment: As simple an error as this may be, I can easily envision a scenario where this typographical error and its associated exception could be useful for a future reader.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The url should be: `https://www.google.com`. Not `https:\\www.google.com`. Change the URL and it should work.

Comment: Thx alot you solved my problem.I was stuck on it for 2 days.